# How to export a csv from a search result in Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a search form using django-filters and I want to export out a .csv with the filtered result. Currently it is giving me a full page of data and I am not sure how to join the 2 views together to utilize the filtering.

**models.py**

```
class account(models.Model):
    Price = models.DecimalField('price', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    User = models.CharField('user', max_length=120, blank=True, null=True,)
    Account_Number = models.CharField('account Number', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True,)
    Date = models.DateField(default=now)
```

**views.py**

```
def stage(request):
    slist = account.objects.all()
    search_list = account.objects.all()
    search_filter = stageFilter(request.GET, queryset=search_list)
    return render(request, 'stage.html', {'slist': slist, 'search': search_filter})

def export_csv(request):
    employees = account.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'  
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow (['User', 'Account Number', 'Price', 'Date'])
    for employee in employees:  
        writer.writerow([employee.User,employee.Account_Number,employee.Price, employee.Date])  
    return response
```

**filters.py**

```
class stageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

class Meta:
    model = account
    fields = ['User', 'Account_Number', 'Price', 'Date']
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('stage/', views.stage, name='stage'),
    path('export_csv', views.export_csv, name='exportcsv')
]
```

Comment: What is your ideal user flow for the user?

Comment: My ideal setup would be to get a filtered .csv once you press the button and right now its giving me everything in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fix for my issue. I obviously needed to incorporate the search/queryset in to the export_csv definition, which I had already tried but it failed. The missing piece of the code was to add request.GET.urlencode() in to the template, which takes the query string from the url and passes the result in to the .csv

**views.py**

```
def export_csv(request):
    employees = account.objects.all()
    search = stageFilter(request.GET, queryset=employees).qs
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'  
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow (['User', 'Account Number', 'Price', 'Date'])
    for e in search.values_list('User', 'Account_Number', 'Price', 'Date'):
        writer.writerow(e)  
    return response
```

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="table-dark">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for item in search.qs%}

            <td>{{item.User}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Account_Number}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
        </tr>
          {% endfor %}
       
    </tbody>
</table>

<div><a href="{% url 'exportcsv' %}?{{request.GET.urlencode}}">
<button type="button" class="button">Export to CSV</button></a></div>
```